# Java: making List from primitive array using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to make a List from a primitive array

```
int[] values={4,5,2,3,42,60,20};
List<Integer> greaterThan4 =
Arrays.stream(values)
        .filter(value -> value > 4)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the last function `collect` gives me an error because it wants other arguments. It wants 3 arguments Supplier, ObjIntConsumer and BiConsumer.

I don't understand why it wants 3 arguments when I have seen different examples that just use `collect(Collectors.toList());` and get the list.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is because `Arrays.stream` returns an `IntStream`. You can call `boxed()` to get a `Stream<Integer>` and then perform the collect operation.

```
List<Integer> greaterThan4 = Arrays.stream(values)
                                   .filter(value -> value > 4)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: + 1 for finding the real problem and the real solution

Answer (score 2):

You're using an array of primitives for one thing, not `Integer`. I suggest you use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like

```
Integer[] values={4,5,2,3,42,60,20};
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using a 3rd party library and would like to avoid boxing the `int` values as `Integer` objects, you could use primitive lists in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
int[] values = {4, 5, 2, 3, 42, 60, 20};
IntList list = IntLists.mutable.withAll(
        Arrays.stream(values).filter(value -> value > 4));

Assertions.assertEquals(IntLists.mutable.with(5, 42, 60, 20), list);
```

You can also convert the `IntStream` to an `IntArrayList` using the `collect` method, but it is more verbose.

```
IntList list = Arrays.stream(values).filter(value -> value > 4)
        .collect(IntArrayList::new, IntArrayList::add, IntArrayList::addAll);

Assertions.assertEquals(IntLists.mutable.with(5, 42, 60, 20), list);
```

You can also just construct the primitive list directly from the primitive array, and use the `select` method which is an inclusive `filter`.

```
IntList list = IntLists.mutable.with(values).select(value -> value > 4);

Assertions.assertEquals(IntLists.mutable.with(5, 42, 60, 20), list);
```

I have blogged about primitive collections in Eclipse Collections [here](https://medium.com/javarevisited/the-missing-java-data-structures-no-one-ever-told-you-about-part-3-d26387b9e66e?source=friends_link&sk=00643d5a044cfa85514cd583963048ce).

**Note**: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `int[] values={4,5,2,3,42,60,20};` to `Integer[] values={4,5,2,3,42,60,20};` because currently you are passing an array of primitive type(`int`) but should you pass array of object i.e. `Integer`